# What should be the loss function for classification problem in pytorch if sigmoid is used in the output layer

Tags: deep-learning, classification, pytorch

I am trying to implement a model for binary classification problem. Up to now, I was using softmax function (at the output layer) together with torch.NLLLoss function to calculate the loss. However, now I want to use the sigmoid function (instead of softmax) at the output layer. If I do that, should I also change the loss function (to BCELoss or [binary_cross_entropy](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy)) or may I still use torch.NLLLoss function ?

Comment: Perhaps a reading of [multilabele vs multiclass](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/what-is-the-difference-between-multiclass-and-multilabel-problem) will help clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sigmoid` function, then you can only do binary classification. It's not possible to do a multi-class classification. The reason for this is because `sigmoid` function always returns a value in the range between 0 and 1. So, for instance one can threshold the value at 0.5 and separate (or classify) it into two classes based on the obtained values.

Regarding the objective function `NLLLoss` - Negative Log Likelihood Loss. It just learns the data distribution. So, it's not a problem as long as that what you're trying to achieve during training.